# Pointer with public array

Tags: java, arrays, pointers, public

Here is the thing- my Main method only calls InitGui. Inside the whole class (basically the whole file, i have the InitGui method and a few public static gui objects. One of the objects is actuall an array

```
public static JButton Keys[] = null;
```

And I have a method called placeKeys that gets the location for each JButton "Keys" and places it on the panel. The whole code works when I do not use this method, basically instead of for i=0 to whatever, I want just call placeKey(arguments here...) instead of 
for each jButton to be placed like this

```
for i=0 to whatever
Keys[i] = new JButton(jBStringArray[i]);
        Keys[i].setLocation(2 + i*kSize,2+row*50);
        Keys[i].setSize(50, kSize);     
        keyboardPane.add(Keys[i]);
```

I have the method written down but it reports a pointer error at the placeKeys when it tries to access the Keys[] , meaning the first line of the method

Hope you understood me

Comment: So what's the real code?  Unfortunately the loop isn't right so I can't say if that's the problem or not.  Also, be sure to explicitly state what your exception is - it's likely `NullPointerException`, but I can't be 100% sure.

Comment: yes - it is NullPointerException

Comment: the loop is called multiple with different arugments, sometimes it is not even called but just these 4 lines are called for 1 value, but I want a method to do these 4 lines...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your for loop (either when you declare it, or, if you rely on the null check, just before the for loop) you need to create the array with `Keys = new JButton[whatever+1];`. Oh and please start your variable names with a lowercase letter - it's the universally-accepted thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
//assuming jBStringArray is already defined here
public static JButton Keys[] = new JButton[jBStringArray.length];
```